# Impersonate change nothing in user identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to do an app and I need user information.
So I Use :

```
var windowsIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as WindowsIdentity
```

and

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

But even if impersonate is on false I get the same result. The result is ok but why when impersonate is on false I hadn't my IIS account user and on true my windows account ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: What is the context of your app? Is this intranet or a publicly available internet application? If the latter you should be looking at Simple Membership (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider) for MVC 4, or the new ASP.NET Identity  (http://www.asp.net/identity) for MVC 5. The latter makes it each to use external authentication sources - such as Facebook and Twitter - via OAuth. Impersonation is often used to allow access to files and resources external to your application - controlling the user the code runs or fetchs resources under.

Comment: Thanks for responding, the context is an intranet.

Comment: Hi. Be aware that .NET 4.5, which MVC5 uses, does not support <identity impersonate="true" />. See this [helpful post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1961337.aspx?Asp+Net+MVC+5+how+to+impersonate+user+on+IIS) which both explains why impersonate has been dropped and provides a work around.